# Create AES-256 address for Google Cloud HSM

Tags: eztz, tezos-signer

How can I create an AES-256 address for import to Google Cloud HSM with Js?

Comment: Using eztz? The `eztz.crypto.generateKeys` does not seem to contain any options for what crypto scheme to use (https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/wiki/Documentation#eztz.crypto) so I'm guessing this is not possible.

Comment: I can understand what address I added to Google Cloud HSM?

Comment: I don't understand your question.